# Correct way of using cuda.jit in Numba

Tags: cuda, numba

Trying to figure out how to do matrix vector multiplication in cuda.jit in Numba, but I'm getting wrong answers

```
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import cuda
m = 2 
n = 3
@cuda.jit('void(f4[:,:], f4[:], f4[:])')
def cu_matrix_vector(A, b, c):
    row = cuda.grid(1)
    if (row < m):
        temp = 0
        for i in range(n):
            temp += A[row, i] * b[i]
        c[row] = temp

A = np.array([[1, -1, 2], [0, -3, 1]], dtype=np.float32)
B = np.array([2, 1, 0], dtype=np.float32)
C = np.empty((2,))

dA = cuda.to_device(A)
dB = cuda.to_device(B)
dC = cuda.to_device(C)

cu_matrix_vector[(m+511)/512, 512](dA, dB, dC)
print(C)
```

The answer is wrong, and can't figure out where I done wrong.
Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 2 errors in your code:

1. numba defaults floating point variables to the same size that python uses by default, i.e. 64-bit floating point.  If you specify 32-bit floating point in your signature:

   ```
   @cuda.jit('void(f4[:,:], f4[:], f4[:])')
   ```

   its important to pass 32-bit floating point variables.  Your `C` (and therefore `dC`) don't match this.  we can fix it with the same method you use for `A` and `B`:

   ```
   C = np.empty((2,), dtype=np.float32)
   ```
2. numba and CUDA need to move data back and forth between device and host.  When you print device results from the host, its important to make sure that you have copied those results back (from `dC`) before printing.  numba doesn't do this automatically for you if you print `C` instead of `dC`.  We can fix this like so:

   ```
   print(dC.copy_to_host())
   ```

With those changes, your code prints the expected result for me.